# Determine if date range fulls within another date range

Tags: php, mysql, date

Looking for some help as been struggling on this for a while.

I have a table of date ranges:

```
"time_from" 2013-06-03 00:00:00, "time_till" 2013-07-03 00:00:00
"time_from" 2013-05-03 00:00:00, "time_till" 2013-06-03 00:00:00
```

Then I have a form where you submit a new date range.

When this form is submitted I want to check that any part of the new date range does not conflict with any part of any of the currently existing date ranges.

Can anyone help, I am not fussed whether this is done in `MySQL` or `PHP`.

Thanks

Comment: PHP's `strtotime()` could help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily with a mysql query

```
select * from table where
$variable_start BETWEEN time_from AND time_till OR $variable_end BETWEEN time_from AND time_till
```

you will have rows if your times falls between your date ranges

Comment: How would this work for comparing a date range to a date range as I assume you are comparing a single date to date range?

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the row exists with same range through sql

```
select if(count(*) >0,'conflicts', 'does not conflict')
from yourTable
where ($startTime between time_from and time_till)
or ($endTime between time_from and time_till)
```

if any of the input date lies the existing date range, it will show conflicts otherwise it will result does not conflict

Comment: This will only check that a start and end dates do not conflict. It will not check that any time between the dates conflicts?

Comment: changed the query to check between ranges

Answer (score 0):

Assuming within means that there is a conflict.

You need to check that for each row:

Your date range START doesnt fall before the current date range START AND your date range end doesnt fall after the current date range START

AND

Your date range START doesnt fall before the current date range START AND your date range end doesnt fall after the current date range END

AND

Your date range START doesnt fall before the current date range END AND your date range end doesnt fall after the current date range START

AND

Your date range START doesnt fall after the current date range START AND your date range end doesnt fall before the current date range END